# Несколько уникальных линий со своими координатами

Tags: диаграммы, google-chart

В Google Charts легко указать как отображать линии с одинаковыми значениями по горизонтальной оси

```
[
   ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
   ['2004',  1000,      400],
   ['2005',  1170,      460],
   ['2006',  660,       1120],
   ['2007',  1030,      540]
]
```

Как задать для каждой линии свой набор точек?

Например в highcharts это делается так

```
series: [{
    data: [
        {x:2001,y: 1000},
        {x:2002, y: 1500}
    ],
    name: "First line"
},
{
    data: [
        {x:2004, y: 2000},
        {x:2005, y: 2500}
    ],
    name: "Second Line"
}]
```